# Continuous background music with winsound module

Tags: python, winsound

So, I have been working on this game called Space Invader. Everything is doing great except for one thing which is the sound. As in the below code, I've imported `winsound` module and it is not doing well. When I fire the bullet it makes the fire noise which I wanted but the problem is that I've also added background music, and whenever I hit fire it stops the background music and starts making fire noises until it hits the target. I want background music to run continuously. I've also seen many Youtube videos but couldn't get any help. Can anyone tell me the mistake which I've made in the below code?

```py
import turtle
import random
import math
import winsound

score = 0
highscore = 0
targets = []
live_remaining = 3

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.title("Space War")
screen.bgcolor("Black")
screen.setup(width=800, height=770)
screen.bgpic("Space.gif")
screen.addshape("Spaceship.gif")
screen.addshape("Missile.gif")
screen.addshape("ufo.gif")
screen.addshape("gameover.gif")
screen.addshape("youwin.gif")
screen.tracer(0)
winsound.PlaySound("bgmusic.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC)

spaceship = turtle.Turtle()
spaceship.speed(0)
spaceship.shape("Spaceship.gif")
spaceship.penup()
spaceship.ht()
spaceship.goto(0, -320)
spaceship.st()
spaceship.direction = "stop"
spaceshipspeed = 15

num_of_targets = 50

for i in range(num_of_targets):
    targets.append(turtle.Turtle())

target_start_x = -250
target_start_y = 275
target_number = 0

for target in targets:
    target.shape("ufo.gif")
    target.penup()
    target.speed(0)
    x=target_start_x + (50 * target_number)
    y=target_start_y
    target.goto(x, y)
    target_number += 1 
    if target_number == 10:
        target_start_y -= 20
        target_number = 0
targetspeed = 0.5

fires=turtle.Turtle()
fires.shape("Missile.gif")
fires.penup()
fires.ht()
fires.speed(0)
fires.goto(0, -340)
fires.direction = "stop"
firesspeed=3

fire = turtle.Turtle()
fire.shape("Missile.gif")
fire.penup()
fire.ht()
fire.speed(0)
fire.goto(0, -340)
fire.direction = "stop"
firespeed = 4
firestate = "ready"

sb=turtle.Turtle()
sb.shape("square")
sb.color("white")
sb.ht()
sb.penup()
sb.goto(0,320)
sb.write("Score: 0 | High Score: 0", align="center", font=("courier", 30, "bold"))

life = turtle.Turtle()
life.shape("square")
life.ht()
life.penup()
life.goto(-350,-350)
life.color("white")
life.write("Life remaining: 3", font=("courier",10,"bold"))


def go_left():
    x = spaceship.xcor()
    x -= spaceshipspeed
    if x < -340:
        x = -340
    spaceship.setx(x)


def go_right():
    x = spaceship.xcor()
    x += spaceshipspeed
    if x > 340:
        x = 340
    spaceship.setx(x)


def go_forward():
    global firestate
    if firestate == "ready":
        firestate = "fire"
        x = spaceship.xcor()
        y = spaceship.ycor()
        fire.setposition(x, y)
        fire.st() 
        winsound.PlaySound("fire.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC)


def move():
    pass


screen.listen() 
screen.onkeypress(go_left, "a")    
screen.onkeypress(go_right, "d")
screen.onkeypress(go_forward, "space")  

while True:
    screen.update()
   
    for target in targets:
        x = target.xcor()
        x += targetspeed
        target.setx(x)

        if target.xcor() > 340:
            targetspeed *= -1
            for t in targets:    
                y = t.ycor()
                y -= 20
                t.sety(y)

        if target.xcor() < -340:
            targetspeed *= -1
            for t in targets:
                y = t.ycor()
                y -= 20
                t.sety(y)

        if fire.distance(target) < 20:
            fire.direction = "stop"
            fire.ht()
            fire.clear()
            firestate = "ready"
            fire.goto(10000000, 1000000)            
            target.goto(0, 10000000) 
            score += 10
            winsound.PlaySound("explosion.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC)

            if score > highscore:
                highscore = score
            sb.clear()
            sb.write("Score: {} | High Score: {}".format(score,highscore), align="center", 
font=("courier", 30, "bold"))

            if score == 500:
                screen.clear()
                screen.bgcolor("black")
                gf = turtle.Turtle()
                gf.shape("youwin.gif")
                gf.goto(0, 0)
                winsound.PlaySound("gamewin.wav",winsound.SND_ASYNC)

        if spaceship.distance(target) < 60:
            spaceship.goto(0, -320)
            target.goto(-320, 300)
            live_remaining -= 1
            winsound.PlaySound("explosion.wav",winsound.SND_ASYNC)

            life.clear()
            life.write("Life remaining: {}".format(live_remaining), font=("courier",10,"bold"))

            if live_remaining == 0:
                screen.clear()
                screen.bgcolor("black")
                gover=turtle.Turtle()
                gover.shape("gameover.gif")
                gover.goto(0, 0)
                winsound.PlaySound("gamelose.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC)  
                replay = input("Press r to retry",)

    y = fire.ycor()
    y += firespeed
    fire.sety(y)
    if fire.ycor() > 300:
        fire.ht()
        firestate = "ready"  

    move()
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Maybe adding the flag [`SND_NOSTOP`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winsound.html#winsound.SND_NOSTOP) would help?

Comment: Nope, by doing this it's playing music but causing game to stop display

Comment: But did you pass both, `SND_ASYNC` and `SND_NOSTOP`? Else it might help to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (without all the GIFs etc., just a screen and music) so that other people can try out the code.

Comment: Nope, it didn't help.